# populate values in textbox from database on selected Index changed event of dropdown in jsp hibernate and spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I have a dropdown. On selecting any value in dropdown iwant to populate values in textbox from database using spring and hibernate and jsp

Comment: Well,Start it on your own.If any problems come back.We are not here  yo to do your job.

Answer (score 0):

First setup your web application with jsp, spring and hibernate.

Use javascript on the page which `onChange` event of drop down makes an ajax call to your service and set the textbox.